# contact form for jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've searched for a solution, but without success. I need a contact form for my jQuery Mobile / PhoneGap app. I've a server with node.js.

Has somebody an working example or code, which I can use?

Comment: Don't know which data is required for your contact form but you can build one using this documentation. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/forms/

Answer (score 0):

## Html

```
<ol data-inset="true" data-role="listview"></ol>
```

## Javascript

```
<script>       

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";
        options.filter="";
        options.multiple=true;
        var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

    }       

    // display the address information for all contacts
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
         var li = '';
         $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
                if(value.name){
                    $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
                       if(key == 'formatted'){
                           name = value;
                       }

                    });
                }
                if(value.phoneNumbers){
                    $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                        phone = value.value;
                    });
                }                    
                li += '<li >'+name+' '+phone+'</li>';
         });


        $("#contact").html(li).trigger('create');
        $("#contact").listview("refresh");

    };

    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ved. I think this is a list of the contacts from my phone, right? I mean a feedback form, to send a message to the admin.

Comment: I want a simple contact form. The user can type in a message and the message is submitted to me by email. The problem is, that php is not allowed at phonegap and my server has node.js. Now, I don't know how to create a contact form.

Comment: you can use email or sms plugin in phonegap.